# Compatition package for CentOS6.6

Tags: centos6, packages

my CentOS 6.6 linux kernel is: 2.6.32-642.6.2.el6.i686 #1 SMP Wed Oct 26 06:14:53 UTC 2016
I want to upgrade my auditd package to newer version, but there are many choices and I don't know which is best suitable:

CentOS i386 Official

1. audit-2.4.5-6.el6.i686.rpm
2. audit-libs-2.4.5-6.el6.i686.rpm
3. audit-libs-devel-2.4.5-6.el6.i686.rpm

CentOS x86_64 Official

1. audit-2.4.5-6.el6.x86_64.rpm
2. audit-libs-2.4.5-6.el6.i686.rpm
3. audit-libs-2.4.5-6.el6.x86_64.rpm
4. audit-libs-devel-2.4.5-6.el6.i686.rpm
5. audit-libs-devel-2.4.5-6.el6.x86_64.rpm

And I can't update from yum too.
Thanks

Comment: If you can't use `yum` to update, then the only way that you can get a later version is to build it from source. You'll have to get the `i686` versions because of you kernel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :D

Comment: audit-2.4.5-6.el6.x86_64.rpm is the normal package, the rest being the x64 and x86 libraries. Just install that one.

Comment: you sure? that server is on production so I need to be carefull every action

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to install `audit-2.4.5-6.el6.x86_64.rpm` and `audit-libs-2.4.5-6.el6.i686.rpm`. You probably do not need `audit-libs-devel` as that's used to compile programs against the library.

You can tell which packages you need by looking at your processor architecture (which you helpfully posted in the question). In this case, it's a 32-bit architecture (`i686`) which is somewhat unusual these days. Technically you might only need the `audit` package, but it won't hurt to also install `audit-libs`.

Comment: any conflic between them?